# @react-native-firebase/firestore@18.8.0 error in ios build

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native, build

I am facing an issue while building a react-native app on iOS as I update all Firebase dependencies to 18.8.0 everything works fine. Still, when I install @react-native-firebase/firestore@18.8.0 I get an error in the fileRNFBFirestoreTransactionModule.m file.

> /Users/mac/Desktop/salon-app/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/firestore/ios/RNFBFirestore/RNFBFirestoreTransactionModule.m:88:83 Definition of 'FIRApp' must be imported from module 'RNFBApp.RCT

[image: error image is here]**Convert_FIRApp' before it is required**

i have updated pod file everything but still issues not resolved is my issue related to firestore version or what i need to do im using *xcode version 15.2 ios build version 13.0*

My AppDelegate.mm file code is here

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Firebase.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];

  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyDAurBSi8KW9fONgSH2auhXWT9_vmTX4-w"];
  self.moduleName = @"SalonApp";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```